# Parameter passed to Handlebars helper appears as the key instead of the value

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm making an Ember.js application, and using Handlebars for templates. I've created a handlebars helpers which currently looks like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('beautify', function(string) {
    var str= new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(string.replace(/_/g, ' '));
    return str;
});
```

And call it like so:

```
        <td class="small-cell">{{beautify foo}}</td>
```

But instead of passing the variable "foo" to the helper, handlebars instead passes the string "foo". This is especially odd, because if I try logging the variable with the helper

```
{{log foo}}
```

The correct string is displayed.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: What version of Ember.js are you using? More recent versions use `Ember.Helper.helper` instead to register helpers.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware. Thank you. It's available in my version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper` instead of `Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper`:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('beautify', function(str) {
    var str= new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString(str.replace(/_/g, ' '));
    return str;
});
```